# How to find all the possible subgroups in a group

Tags: python, recursion

Lets say we have the group 1,2,3 So the possible subgroups are:

```
    {1,2,3}
    {1} {2,3}
    {1,2} {3}
    {1,3} {2}
    {1} {2} {3}
```

You get the idea.

I have to do it using recursion. What I have so far (doesn't work), and it's a bit different.
The idea is that you have a list of ints that represents cubes (to build a tower), and you want to build as many towers as you can of a certain height. So let's say you get the list of
cubes `[5,2,6,6,1,1,4]` and the height you want is `7`, then the best build would be `[5,2] [6,1] [6,1] [4]`.

code:

```
def find_tower(blocks, height):

    def solve(groups, cur_group, index):
        if index == len(blocks):
            return groups
        if sum(cur_group) == height:
            new_group = list(groups)
            new_group.append(cur_group)
            return solve(new_group, [], index)
        elif sum(cur_group) > height:
            return solve(groups, [], index)

        r1 = solve(groups, cur_group + [blocks[index]], index+1)
        r2 = solve(groups, cur_group, index+1)
        return max(r1, r2, key=lambda x: len(x))
    return solve([], [], 0)
```

but I just get `[5,2] [6,1]`. Any ideas?

Comment: why `[4]` is a `7` height tower? can you explain better what your algorithm suppose to do?

Comment: You’re looking for [set partitions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_a_set). You can likely find some algorithms for that.

Comment: 4 is not a tower, its just the remainders, you need to build as many towers as you can

Comment: i want it to be a very general pure recursion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main problem was that you didn't repeat on values you didn't use, example:
First you take 5,2
than 6,6, but its not good so you skip and than take 6,1
but you will never take the first 6 again, and get another combo of 6,1.
thats why you have to repeat all the values after you pick one combo.

code(probably can be better, used you logic):

```
    def find_tower(blocks, height):

def solve(groups, cur_group, index):
    if sum(cur_group) == height:
        new_group = list(groups)# if tower is on right height
        new_group.append(cur_group)# add to groups of towers
        return solve(new_group, [], 0)
    if index == len(blocks):# if index max
        return groups
    elif sum(cur_group) > height:# if its higher than height
        return groups
    elif blocks[index] is None:# if its a None index skip
        return solve(groups, cur_group, index+1)

    temp = blocks[index]
    blocks[index] = None# changing used value to none
    r1 = solve(groups, cur_group + [temp], index+1)
    blocks[index] = temp# puttin back used value
    r2 = solve(groups, cur_group, index+1)
    return max(r1, r2, key=lambda x: len(x))# return longer group
return solve([], [], 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not saying the following is efficient but it gives you an idea on how to build the result recursively:

```
import itertools

def partitions(items, n):
    if n == 1:
        return [set([e]) for e in items]
    results = partitions(items, n - 1)
    for i, j in itertools.combinations(range(len(results)), 2):
        newresult = results[i] | results[j]
        if newresult not in results:
            results.append(newresult)
    return results


items = [1,2,3]
print partitions(items, len(items))
# [set([1]), set([2]), set([3]), set([1, 2]), set([1, 3]), set([2, 3]), set([1, 2, 3])]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple approach using recursion. The idea is that for a list consisting of `x` and some other elements `xs`, the set of subsets is all subsets of `xs`, plus the subsets of `xs` with `x` appended.

```
from copy import *

def all_subsets(xs):
  if not xs:
    return [[]]
  else:
    x = xs.pop()
    subsets = all_subsets(xs)
    subsets_copy = deepcopy(subsets) # NB you need to use a deep copy here!
    for s in subsets_copy:
      s.append(x)
    subsets.extend(subsets_copy)
    return subsets
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with

```
def find_tower(blocks,height):

    groups = []
    blocks = sorted(blocks,reverse=True)

    while sum(blocks) > height:
        curgroup = []
        running_total = height
        while sum(curgroup) < height:
            possibilities = [block for block in blocks if
                             block <= running_total]
            if possibilities:
                selected_block = blocks.index(max(possibilities))
            else:
                break
            running_total -= blocks[selected_block]
            curgroup.append(blocks.pop(selected_block))
        groups.append(curgroup)
    groups = groups+[blocks]
    return groups
```

Output:

```
IN:  print(find_tower([13,12,11,10,9,8,1,1,1,1,1,1],13))


OUT: [[13], [12, 1], [11, 1, 1], [10, 1, 1, 1], [9], [8]]
```

EDIT: D'oh! When I looked at this problem I didn't see the requirement that it be done via recursion. I hate recursion...... Let me see if I can get it to work, but give me awhile.